Prove that $L^2=L^+ \oplus L^-$.
Let's consider $L^2(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \mid \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^2\ d\lambda<+\infty\}$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.
So, $L^2$ endowed with the standard inner product is an Hilbert space.
We define that:

$L^+=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid f(t)=f(-t) \space \mathrm{a.e.} \space t\in \mathbb{R}\}$, the subspace of even functions.

$L^-=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid f(t)=-f(-t) \space \mathrm{a.e.} \space t\in \mathbb{R}\}$, the subspace of odd functions.


I have to prove that $L^2=L^+ \oplus L^-$.
I've already proved that $L^+$ is a closed vectorial subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and now I want to show that $\left(L^+\right)^\perp=L^-$.
If it holds, then $L^2=L^+\oplus \left(L^+\right)^\perp=L^+\oplus L^- $.
$(\supseteq)$ Taken $g\in L^{-}$, I want to show that $\langle f,g\rangle =0, \space \forall f\in L^+$.
$$\langle f,g\rangle =0, \space \forall f\in L^+\iff \int_{\mathbb{R}}fg\ d\lambda =0,\space \forall f\in L^+$$
Let be $f\in L^+$ a generic even function, then I have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)g(t)\ dt=0= -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(-t)g(-t)\ dt\iff$$ $$\iff\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)g(t)\ dt-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(s)g(s)\ ds =0$$
saying that $s=-t$.
Therefore, $\langle f,g\rangle =0$ and so $g\in (L^+)^\perp $ thanks to the arbitrariness of $f\in L^+$.
$(\subseteq)$ Let $g\in (L^+)^\perp$. Then,
$$\langle g,f\rangle =0, \space \forall f\in L^+\iff \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t)f(t)\ dt=0, \space \forall f\in L^+ \iff $$ $$\iff\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t)f(t)\ dt=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(-t)f(-t)\ dt\iff$$
$$\iff \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigl[g(t)+g(-t)\Bigl]f(t)\ dt=0 \iff \Bigl(g(t)+g(-t)\Bigl)f(t)=0$$
Assuming that $f$ is not the null function (otherwise it's always true), I have that $g(t)=-g(-t)$ almost everywhere.
Therefore, $g\in L^-$.
Is my proof correct? Can it be improved? In particular, $(\supseteq)$ is lecit?

Maybe I’m missing something but can’t you use the projectors $f\mapsto (x\mapsto (f(x)+f(-x))/2$ and $f\mapsto (x\mapsto (f(x)-f(-x))/2$?

Yes, a friend of mine and I proved using those two functionals. But I wanted to try to proved the two inclusions that way. Do you think my reasoning works? Are there any clarifications to be made?

No you reasoning works, you should just be wary of the misuse of equivalences. It selles to be valid but I would avoid it since you only need one direction

Are you referring to the fact that they are all valid almost everywhere?

No no just a rédaction preference, I tend to not use equivalences unless I need to prove the equivalence

Okay, so you say I have to change the $\iff$ in $\Longrightarrow$?

No no it is not needed it was just a remark. It avoids having to verify both directions each time and double the chance of mistake. Your proof is perfectly valid and if you are able to do so you will have no trouble going through hilbert spaces

Perfect, thanks for the useful comments you made. Have a good continuation!
